# Nested Table Entries with MySQL + TypeORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have been using TypeORM in my Node + React + MySQL Project for entity Management.

### I need to insert duplicate records in tables having parent-child relationship.

The relationship hierarchy is like this:

Table A

Table B (Child of A)

Table C (Child of B),

Moreover, Table C has a parent-child relationship with itself.

---

Entity Structure is like this:

> Table A

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'int',
    unsigned: true,
    name: 'id',
})
id: number;

@Column('varchar', {
    nullable: false,
    length: 250,
    name: 'title',
})
title: string;

@OneToMany(() => B, (b: B) => b.a, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE' ,
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    })
bs: B[];
```

> Table B

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'int',
    unsigned: true,
    name: 'id',
})
id: number;

@ManyToOne(() => A, (a: A) => a.bs,
    {  nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'a_id'})
a: A | null;

@OneToMany(() => C, (c: C) => c.b, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
})
cs: C[];
```

> Table C

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'int',
    unsigned: true,
    name: 'id',
})
id: number;

@ManyToOne(() => B, (b: B) => b.cs,
    {  nullable: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'b_id'})
b: B | null;

@ManyToOne(() => C, (c: C) => c.cs,
    {  nullable: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'parent_id'})
parent: C | null;

@OneToMany(() => C, (c: C) => c.parent, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
})
cs: C[];
```

---

So, here is the task that I am supposed to do...
I need to duplicate some records of `Table B` (& records in child Table C should also be duplicated with the new b_id generated), 
I will have the array of b_id.

Also see that `Table C` has ManyToOne and OneToMany relationship with itself.

I am able to do this with number of loops, but there must be some way to utilise these relations among the tables.

So, How can I duplicate the records using TypeORM ?

> Thanks in Advance .....

Comment: were you able to resolve this? i am looking for the same solution...